# Does hasManyThrough ignore global scopes on the intermediate table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have 3 tables: companies, games and tests.

- Companies have many games
- Games have many tests

The `Game` model has a global scope, which I can confirm is working:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    $builder->where('type', 'live');
}
```

Any direct queries I do using the `Game` model will only return results where the game type is set to "live".

I am using `return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Test', 'App\Games')` in my `Company` model to get all tests for a particular company.

However, this is returning results for all games, regardless of their type.

So I am wondering if using `hasManyThrough` bypasses the global scope that I've set in the `Game` model?

If so, is there any way around this? I want to make sure that all queries I'm doing are filtering out any games that aren't set to "live".

Cheers

Comment: Haven't tested this but try escaping the ` \ ` in `'App\Test'`

Comment: This is a known (and complicated) issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23039#issuecomment-414184128 You can either apply the scope manually or combine two separate `HasMany` relationships.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, unfortunately that's the opposite of my problem. At the moment the global scope _isn't_ being applied and I want it to be applied.

Comment: The last comment is about your issue.

Comment: Ah yes @JonasStaudenmeir my mistake. No answer though. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `->withoutGlobalScopes()` to definition of relationship

```
class User extends Model
{
   public function games()
   {
      return $this->hasManyThrough(Test::class, Games::class)
             ->withoutGlobalScopes();
   }
}
```

Comment: I want the global scope to be applied. At the moment, it's not being applied.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to manually apply your global scopes.

Something like:

```
public function tests()
{
    $ret = $this->hasManyThrough(Test::class, Games::class);
    (new Games())->registerGlobalScopes($ret);
    return $ret;
}
```